# Simple Trigger Error?! PL/SQL: ORA-00933:

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, sql-insert, database-trigger

I am attempting to create a trigger that will insert values into an audit table for approval by an admin user. The trigger will insert new values that are added into a consultant table into this audit table.

I have re-jigged the trigger a lot but cannot seem to bypass the compilation error! I assume it's something small?

```
DROP TABLE   MyAuditTable;
CREATE TABLE MyAuditTable (
    audit_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    new_name VARCHAR2 (30),
    new_postcode VARCHAR2 (20),
    status     VARCHAR2 (15), 
    CONSTRAINT pk_MyAuditTable  PRIMARY KEY ( audit_id )
); 


DROP sequence MySeq;
Create sequence MySeq MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;

drop trigger MyTrigger;
create trigger MyTrigger
after insert on my_consultant_table
for each row
begin
    insert into MyAuditTable values (
        MySeq.nextval, :new.con_name, 
        :new.con_postcode, 
        'Pending'
    )
    from my_consultant_table;
end;
/
```

> ERROR: PL/SQL: ORA-00933:

So the audit table should now have the newly inputted data from the consultant table, which contains name and postcode attributes. Another trigger will fire so that when the status is changed, these changes are permitted.

Thank You!

Comment: Just remove `from my_consultant_table`

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
from my_consultant_table
```

Is unnecessary.

Should be:

```
insert into MyAuditTable values (MySeq.nextval, :new.con_name, :new.con_postcode, 'Pending');
```

Answer (score 2):

This ORA-00933 denotes a syntax error in your trigger declaration :

```
begin
    insert into MyAuditTable values (
        MySeq.nextval, :new.con_name, 
        :new.con_postcode, 
        'Pending'
    )
    from my_consultant_table;
end;
```

The trailing `from my_consultant_table` does not make sense, just remove it and you should be fine :

```
begin
    insert into MyAuditTable values (
        MySeq.nextval, :new.con_name, 
        :new.con_postcode, 
        'Pending'
    );
end;
```

Comment: Ah perfect! I assumed I had to state the table name. The trigger runs perfectly but no data is being inserted into the audit table?

Comment: @JazzyB : it should get inserted... did you commit your transaction ? Can you see the inserted data in my_consultant_table ?

Comment: I have received the following error: failed to parse SQL query:
ORA-00904: "PERMISSIONS": invalid identifier.. I have a permissions column on the end of my consultant table so that a consultant can only view their own data using UPPER APP_USER (which works fine)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
begin
insert into MyAuditTable 
   select
    MySeq.nextval,
    :new.con_name, 
    :new.con_postcode, 
    'Pending'
   from dual;
end;
```

One Tip: When u create a sequence and always use from 1 to 9999999.... anc increment one by one.
Just use

```
create sequence owner.table nocache;
```